# Design data model for messaging system with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, messagebox, datamodel

I am new to Cassandra and trying to build a data model for messaging system. I found few solutions but none of them exactly match my requirements. There are **two main requirements**:

1. Get a list of last messages for a particular user, from all other users, sorted by time.
2. Get a list of messages for one-to-one message history, sorted by time as well.

I thought of something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
  to_user text,
  from_user_text,
  time text,
  msg text,
  PRIMARY KEY((to_user,from_user),time) 
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

But this design has few issues, like I wont be able to satisfy **first requirement** since this design requires to pass from_user as well. And also  this would be inefficient when number of (to_user,from_user) pair increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. That one table won't satisfy both queries, so you will need two tables. One for each query. This is a core concept with Cassandra data modeling. Query driven design.

So the query looking for messages to a user:

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
  to_user text,
  from_user_text,
  time text,
  msg text,
  PRIMARY KEY((to_user),time) 
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Messages from a user to another user.

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
  to_user text,
  from_user_text,
  time text,
  msg text,
  PRIMARY KEY((to_user),from_user,time) 
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Slight difference from yours: from_user is a clustering column and not a part of the partition key. This is minimize the amount of select queries needed in application code.

It's possible to use the second table to satisfy both queries, but you will have to supply the 'from_user' to use a range query on time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It will satisfy my both requirements. But the first table will give me all the messages from all the from_users sorted by time, that means I won't be able to get messages uniquely from different from_users. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: The second table can do that. 'select * from chat where to_user='X' and from_user='Y';

Comment: I want to check for all the users, not just from_user=Y. Like a fb messenger, it will show only the last msg of all the from_users, but in timely order.

Comment: Easy enough. Just switch the order of the clustering column in the second table: PRIMARY KEY((to_user),time,from_user) That will get you a time ordered list of messages with the from_user

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My question is for example I want to display list of latest messages but from UNIQUE form_users, and display only last messages from those from_users based on time. Its like when you open facebook messenger, you see your chat list ordered by time from different from_users.

Comment: Why do both tables have the same name? Do you need to do the insert once, or twice?